# Efficiently get next value after range and previous value before range

Tags: sql-server

I have a series of measurements ordered ascending by a Coordinate (in millimeter), but it might as well be a timestamp.
The distance between 2 measurements is **irregular**.

I need all measurements in a given range, but to know/interpolate the values at the start and end of that range, I also need the first value after the range and the last value before the range. Unless there happens to be a value right at the edge, then I can use that value.

The best I can come up with is to first get the Coordinates outside the range and use those to query all values in the extended range:

```
declare @from int = 350000; 
declare @to int = 550000;

declare @min_coord int = (
        select ISNULL(max(coordinate), @from) as coord FROM [dbo].[Table] where Coordinate <= @from AND [other parts of primary key]
);
declare @max_coord int = (
        select ISNULL(min(coordinate), @to) as coord FROM [dbo].[Table] where Coordinate >= @to AND [other parts of primary key]
);
select * FROM [dbo].[Table]  where @min_coord <= Coordinate AND Coordinate <= @max_coord  AND [other parts of primary key] order by Coordinate asc;
```

But the query plan looks very inefficient. The 2 queries to get the max/min coordinates take 2* 27% of the cost, while getting the actual data only takes 46% of the total cost.

It feels like there should be an efficient way to get this data in 1 pass instead of 3.

Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B16AtQ936

---

We are using SQL Server 2016 or newer.

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [other parts of primary key],
    [other parts of primary key],
    [other parts of primary key],
    [Coordinate] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Values...]
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [other parts of primary key],
    [other parts of primary key],
    [other parts of primary key],
    [Coordinate] ASC
)
```

Comment: "*But the query plan looks very inefficient. The 2 queries to get the max/min coordinates take 2* **27% of the cost, while getting the actual data only takes 46% of the total cost.*" - We have no way of knowing the "*efficiency*" of the query without looking at the query plan. The Costs you're referring to are estimates and are rather meaningless. They're also relative to the plans and most total 100%. Please upload your actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and then link them in your post, for help with performance questions.

Comment: I have added the actual plan. To clarify, I am not worried about the plan/performance of each of the 3 subqueries. I am trying to find a way to avoid explicitly searching for the min/max

Comment: Thanks! FWIW, your question asks about efficiency, but the plan you provided only took around 100ms to execute. While I'm sure it's possible to rewrite your query as a single atomic query, it doesn't mean it'll be any more efficient to execute (and actually could even be less efficient to do so).

Comment: There is nothing inefficient about that plan. There is a Seek followed by Top 1 in the first two, with no residual predicate, so only 1 row is ever read. Then a final query with a Seek again. The Cost isn't really worth looking at, but you may find it better to just do one big query using joins.